# Displaying nested dictionary in Jinja2

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, jinja2

I have the following Jinja2 template:

```
{% block body %}
    {% for key in tree recursive %}
        {% set outer_loop = loop %}
        {% for subkey in tree[key] %}
            {% if subkey == 'R' %}
                {{ tree[key][subkey] }}
            {% else %}
                {{ outer_loop(dict([(subkey, tree[key][subkey])])) }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock body %}
```

where `tree` is a Python dictionary such as:

```
    tree = {"A": {"R": [1, 2, 3], "B": {"R": [4, 5, 6]}}}
```

and `dict()` is the [Python library function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

The issue is that the template displays only `[1, 2, 3]` and not `[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6]` as expected.

Clearly I am misunderstanding something about how recursion works in Jinja; any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why did you use the 'double for' to control it?
I'm trying to use the 'single for' as follows to code and it looks like it is okay:

```
 from jinja2 import Template

 template = Template(
 """
     {%- for key, value in tree.items() recursive%}
         {%-if key != "R"%}
             {{loop(value.items())}}
         {%- else  %}
             {{value}}
         {%- endif %}
     {%- endfor%}
 """)

 print template.render(tree = {"A": {"R": [1, 2, 3], "B": {"R": [4, 5, 6]}}})
```

I hope it's useful to you with my poor english :)