# How to display a nested dictionary using jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, recursion, nested, jinja2

I have the following dictionary:

```
result = {1: {4: {6: {}, 7: {}, 8: {}}, 5: {}}, 2: {}, 3: {}}
```

My goal is to display it showing its hierarchy like so:

```
1
    4
       6
       7
       8
    5
2
3
```

I was able to achieve my goal using a recursive function in python:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0):
    msg = ''
    for key, value in d.items():
        msg += '\t' * indent + str(key) + '\n'
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            msg += pretty(value, indent+1)
        else:
            msg += '\t' * (indent+1) + str(value) + '\n'
    return msg

msg = pretty(result)
print(msg)
```

Now I would like to pass the dictionary to the `render_template` function of the flask library and use jinja2 in order to replicate the same result. I tried the following line of code but nothing happens:

```
{%- for key, value in result.items() recursive%}
    {{loop(value.items())}}
{%- else  %}
    {{value}}
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor%}
```

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Note: I based my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931448/displaying-nested-dictionary-in-jinja2).

Comment: Why don't you simply register your `pretty` function as a jinja2 filter?

Answer (score 0):

Your template must print the keys rather than the values.

A convenient way to know the recursion depth (for the indentation) is the `loop.depth0` variable.

So try this:

```
from jinja2 import Template

result = {1: {4: {6: {}, 7: {}, 8: {}}, 5: {}}, 2: {}, 3: {}}

template = Template(
"""
    {% for key, value in dict.items() recursive %}
        {{'\t' * loop.depth0}}{{key}}
        {{-loop(value.items())-}}
    {% endfor %}
""")

print (template.render(dict=result))
```